# How do you extract an html snippet from a xml file using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I have javascript code that pulls information for a web page from an xml file and generates html and inserts the data. this works well.

```
getElementsByTagName("XmlNode")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

when I change the data to an html hyperlink block nodeValue returns null.

`<XmlNode><a href='URL'>URL text</a></XmlNode>`

Is there some other property to use to return the contents of this XML node?

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to get the nodeValue of `<a>` rather than the text node inside of it. You can either add another .childNodes[0] to the chain to get to the text node or use .textContent in place of .nodeValue

Comment: No that just returns 'undefined' unfortunatly

Comment: Are you using both (extra childNodes[0] and .textContent) rather than one or the other?

Answer (score 0):

You should use  CDATA to hold markup inside your XML nodes.

```
<![CDATA[  html mark up  ]]>


<XmlNode><![CDATA[<a href='URL'>URL text</a>]]></XmlNode>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out to do this:

```
var xmlSerializer = new XMLSerializer();
function innerXml(node)
{
return xmlSerializer.serializeToString(node)
}
```

Source: http://forums.asp.net/t/1341879.aspx/1

Edit:
After doing a little more research I actually used this:

```
function innerXml(node)
{
    var innerXml = "";
    var nodes = node.childNodes;
    for(q=0;q<nodes.length;q++)
    {
        if (typeof window.XMLSerializer != "undefined")
            innerXml += xmlSerializer.serializeToString(nodes[q]);

        else if (typeof nodes[q].xml != "undefined")
            innerXml += nodes[q].xml;
    }

    innerXml = innerXml.trim();

    return innerXml;
}
```